# Other expressions for "Don't give up (or quit) your day job"

Tags: expressions

"Don't give up (or quit) your day job"

I am sure everyone has heard of this overused retort. It is generally used in the context where one feels the performance of an act has failed miserably.

Are there any other expressions that can be employed instead of this?

Comment: "give up the ghost" could be one... Although it's more related to death...

Comment: Small point: the usual expression is "Don't give up (or quit) your day job".

Comment: ***don't give up your day job***: (idiomatic, often humorous) Somewhat sarcastic but usually good-natured advice used to criticise a person's degree of talent (especially in music or other performing arts), implying that he or she could not make a living from it. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/don%27t_give_up_your_day_job#English

Comment: Maybe "many are called but few are chosen"(Matthew 22:14) could be used.

Comment: One could always say "you suck" but that would be more of an insult.

Comment: Good try http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22192/does-good-try-always-mean-good-efforts-but-ultimately-you-didnt-succeed-at-it

Comment: Where’d you learn to do that? Trump University?

Comment: *Not quite ready for Broadway.*

Answer (score 5):

> **don't call us, we'll call you**
>   *informal*
>   Used as a dismissive way of saying that someone has not been
>   successful in an audition or job application.

[en.oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/don%27t_call_us,_we%27ll_call_you)